# Disable reactive Elasticsearch client

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-webflux, spring-data-elasticsearch

My spring-boot (version 2.4.1) application was successfully connected to an ElasticSearch(v7.9.3) instance using the autowired org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient (I just had to specify the application properties and it worked).

In a new phase of the project a dependency with spring-boot-starter-webflux was added to use some reactive logic to call an external webservice. (which has nothing to do with my elasticsearch connection)

But now suddenly the elasticsearch client also tries to connect using reactor and I got errors like:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.NoReachableHostException:
Host 'https://elastic-dev.company.intra:9200:9200' not reachable. Cluster state is offline. 
Caused by: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.NoReachableHostException:
Host 'https://elastic-dev.company.intra:9200:9200' not reachable. Cluster state is offline.
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.SingleNodeHostProvider.lambda$lookupActiveHost$4(SingleNodeHostProvider.java:108) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.1.2.jar!/:4.1.2]
```

I know there is a configuration issue with :9200:9200 but I would like to just disable the use of reactor for my Elasticsearch client so it just uses the old way (I still need my Elasticseach client). Is this possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: That's nothing that Spring Data Elasticsearch can do something about. That's something that people who know the internals of Spring Boot should answer. On idea though: Try to use `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = ReactiveElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration.class)` on your application class

Answer (score 6):

After searching further I found a solution which was also suggested by P.J.Meish: disable the AutoConfiguration classes regarding the reactive elasticsearch:

I preferred the config in application.properties:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=\
  org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchReactiveHealthContributorAutoConfiguration,\
  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ReactiveElasticsearchRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ReactiveElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration
```

Comment: I had the same issue while using Spring Boot 2.5.5 and ES 7.15.0, trying out the above solution didn't work for me. While earlier my spring boot process would crash due to its dependency on elasticsearch service, now it hangs and I have no clue what's happening..