# NoReachableHostException when Reactive Springboot java app try to connect to ElasticSerach on AWS

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I was writing some Simple Spring boot app to connect to Elasticsearch(Open Search) on AWS.  Here is the versions of  dependencies added to the app:

```
spring-boot-starter Ver 2.6.2
    spring-boot-starter-webflux Ver 5.3.14
    spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch  Ver 4.30 
    Spring-core Ver 5.3.14
    org.elasticsearch Ver 7.15.2
    io.netty  Ver 4.1.72   
    reactor.core Ver 3.4.13
```

When I try to hit the endpoint I get the following error.

```
searchForPage failed:
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.NoReachableHostException: Host 'vpc-dev-i6o7flf44543kxt36fhamxh3qy.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/200.212.124.178:443' not reachable. Cluster state is offline.
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.SingleNodeHostProvider.lambda$lookupActiveHost$3(SingleNodeHostProvider.java:101)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:220)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:137)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.complete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:284)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:187)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:232)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2058)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onComplete(MonoIgnoreElements.java:89)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:549)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142)
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:400)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:419)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:473)*
```

Here is the code that calls searchForPage():

```java
private Flux<SearchResults> stream(SearchCriteria searchCriteria, 
    ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate reactiveElasticsearchTemplate, 
    Supplier<ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate> supplier) {
    NativeSearchQuery query = searchCriteriaToQueryConverterWithoutAggregations 
        .convert(searchCriteria);
    query.setPageable(Pageable.unpaged());
    logger.info("search criteria for the streaming service: " + searchCriteria);
    return reactiveElasticsearchTemplate
        .search(query, SearchResults.class, IndexCoordinates.of(indexName))
        .doOnComplete(() -> logger.info("Results Returned from stream API"))
        .onErrorResume(error->{
            logger.error(ErrorCodes.ES.toString(), error);
            return supplier.get().search(
                query, SearchResults.class, IndexCoordinates.of(indexName));})
        .map(searchHit -> searchHit.getContent());
}
```

Here is the code that configures reactive client:

```java
ReactiveElasticsearchClient initializeElasticRestClient() {
    String ENDPOINT_PORT 
        = "vpc-dev-i6o7flf44543kxt36fhamxh3qy.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:443";
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
        .connectedTo(ENDPOINT_PORT)
        .usingSsl()
        .withConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5000))
        .withSocketTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5000))
         // adding interceptor to sign the request for AWS     
        .withHttpClientConfigurer(hacb -> hacb.addInterceptorLast(interceptor))  
        .build();
    return DefaultReactiveElasticsearchClient.create(clientConfiguration);  
}
```

In the logs  i see the following which makes me think the connection is happening ,but it fails during the completion process

```
reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations  [7f326663-1, L:/200.212.124.162:8443 - R:/200.212.124.172:16002] Last HTTP response frame
reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations  [8bbbb248, L:/200.212.124.162:8443 - R:/200.212.124.203:1908] Increasing pending responses, now 1
reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations  [9734afa6, L:/200.212.124.162:8443 - R:/200.212.124.172:16086] Increasing pending responses, now 1
reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider   [c04eba45, L:/200.212.124.201:8443 - R:/200.212.124.203:39526] SSL enabled using engine sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl@762e3341
reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations  [c04eba45, L:/200.212.124.201:8443 - R:/200.212.124.203:39526] New http connection, requesting read
reactor.netty.transport.TransportConfig [c04eba45, L:/200.212.124.201:8443 - R:/200.212.124.203:39526] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.sslReader = reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider$SslReadHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerCodec), (reactor.left.httpTrafficHandler = reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider   [b92129ad, L:/200.212.124.201:8443 - R:/200.212.124.172:41114] SSL enabled using engine sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl@6ec2a10c
io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler [id: 0xc04eba45, L:/200.212.124.201:8443 - R:/200.212.124.203:39526] HANDSHAKEN: protocol:TLSv1.2 cipher suite:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations  [b92129ad, L:/200.212.124.201:8443 - R:/200.212.124.172:41114] New http connection, requesting read
reactor.netty.transport.TransportConfig [b92129ad, L:/200.212.124.201:8443 - R:/200.212.124.172:41114] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.sslReader = reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider$SslReadHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerCodec), (reactor.left.httpTrafficHandler = reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations  [c04eba45, L:/200.212.124.201:8443 - R:/200.212.124.203:39526] Increasing pending responses, now 1
reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer    [c04eba45-1, L:/200.212.124.201:8443 - R:/200.212.124.203:39526] Handler is being applied: org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter@307f4807
reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations  [c04eba45-1, L:/200.212.124.201:8443 - R:/200.212.124.203:39526] Detected non persistent http connection, preparing to close
```

I am new to both Spring Flux and Elastic search. Any help on this greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So the exception is just a generic exception they throw when something goes wrong, which can be very confusing, you can see my answer here [Connecting to ES with Spring Data Elasticsearch (reactive) gives error host not reachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69607732/connecting-to-es-with-spring-data-elasticsearch-reactive-gives-error-host-not/70851287#70851287)

You should probably try and debug it in localhost with ssh tunnel at first, sure you will get your answer in no time!

My guess is permissions....